# Running script on SQL database from SQL Developer

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SQL database that has a schema on it. I am trying to run a script on this schema from SQL Developer. The problem I'm having is actually doing this from SQL Developer. In the upper right hand corner of the SQL Worksheet screen I can choose the database, but I can't choose the schema. For instance, I need it to run on FLL.dbo. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: "SQL Developer" the tool, or do you mean Management Studio?

Comment: @gbn I meant SQL Developer but I found out that I needed to use Management Studio. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scripts target objects within a database

the script itself should identify each object using schemaName.objectname syntax